# Multidimensional arraylist indexOf?

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, indexof

I'm having an issue with finding some data I have put into my multidimensional arraylist. I basically have an arraylist full of arraylists...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> array = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

So now I want to use indexOf to find the arraylist that contains specific data because I'm comparing it to other data in the same arraylist.

For example, I know I can use a for loop to find this data --

```
for (i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
{
    if (array.get(a).get(0) == array.get(i).get(0))
        //then do something
}
```

But I thought it'd be easier to use indexOf or lastindexOf. Does anyone know the correct way I would use it? I'm thinking it's something like

```
array.indexOf(array.get(????).get(0))
```

but I'm not sure :(

Comment: i think the only way to use indexOf here would be inside afor loop.

Comment: what object are you looking for? What's a in array.get(**a**).get(0) in second snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible. More than that

```
array.indexOf(array.get(????).get(0))
```

is incorrect, since `array.get(????).get(0)` would be an Integer and `array` is an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s, not `Integer`s.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I guess a for loop it is! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use external libraries? If yes then [guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) defines Iterables.indexOf(Iterable, Predicate)

Then you can look up you array like this:

```
final int whatYoureLookingFor = 1232;
int index = Iterables.indexOf(array, new Predicate<ArrayList<Integer>>() {
        public boolean apply(ArrayList<Integer> a) {
             return a.contains(whatYoureLookingFor);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First we need a coordinate container. Then we need a lookup method. This has them both using a factory method. Then you can pass the MultiIndex a list and it will retrieve the value there.

```
class MultiIndex<E> {

    static <E> MultiIndex<E> indexOf(List<List<E>> list, E e) {
        for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            List<E> in = list.get(i);
            int index = in.indexOf(e);
            if(index > -1) return new MultiIndex(i,index);
        }
        return null;
    }
    int outside;
    int inside;
    private MultiIndex(int out, int in) {
        outside = out;
        inside = in;
    }

    E get(List<List<E>> list) {
        return list.get(outside).get(inside);
    }
}
```